# Possible order of $ab$ when orders of $a$ and $b$ are known.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $a,b\in G$ be elements of a finite group $G$. We know $\operatorname{ord}(a)=m$ and $\operatorname{ord}(b)=n$. In dependence of $m$ and $n$ what are the possible values of $\operatorname{ord}(ab)$?

So strictly speaking I'm looking for a function $f:\mathbb N^2\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$.

Note that the restriction of $G$ being finite is no weakening of the problem. In case $n,m>1$ we could always add $\infty$ to the result of $f(m,n)$.

Comment: If the group is not specified I think $ord (ab)$ can be any multiple of $LCM(m, n)$ which divides the order of the group

Comment: if a and b commutes then @brick' claim is true, for example f(x)=x and f(x)=1-x then it isnot true

Comment: @brick I think that's only true if the group is abelian (i.e., the group operation is commutative)

Comment: Yeah, @RaziehNoori, that's right my bad

Comment: I believe $$f(m,n)=\begin{cases}\mathbb N&m=n\\\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}&m\neq n.\end{cases}$$ But I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635754

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$. If $a$ has order $m$ and $b$ has order $n$, what can we say
about the order of $ab$? The following theorem, proved in Milne's lecture notes on group theory, shows that we can say nothing at all.

*THEOREM 1.64* For any integers $m,n, r > 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, and $ab$ has order $r$.

Comment: Can you sketch the proof?

Comment: For the proof see Theorem $1.64$ [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf).

Comment: Nice proof and probably also nice book. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is it possible to find a particular group where two elements have order three but their product has order 5?

Comment: Yes, Milne gives such a group in his proof, namely $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for a suitable prime power $q$.