# A order 5 element consisting of product of two order three elements

Tags: group-theory

Can we find a specific example of a group where two of its element has order 3 but its product has order five.

The question here [possible order of product of two elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418287/possible-order-of-ab-when-order-of-a-and-b-are-known) says that  there exists such group.

But can someone find a specific example?

Comment: Particularly relevant is Dietrich Burde's [answer to linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1418294/120540) and the comment exchange.

Comment: thanx, i missed those comments

Comment: The proof of Theorem $1.64$ in Milne's lecture notes gives "a specific example". Milne constructs elements $a$ and $b$ of arbitrary order $m,n>1$ in the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for a suitable prime power $q$, such that $ab$ has arbitrary order $r>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $S_5$, we have $(123)\circ(345)=(12345)$.

(Apply $(345)$ first and then $(123)$.)