# If $g$ and $h$ are group elements of order $mn$ what is the order of $(gh)^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The question proposes that if:
$$|g|=|h|=mn$$
then
$$|(gh)^m|=n$$
where $m$ and $n$ are any positive integers.
 I either have to prove that this is true or provide a counter-example. I have tried some basic examples from the integers modulo $10$ as well as trying $h=g^{-1}$ but nothing I have tried contradicts the statement. Is this true for the general case? How would I go about proving it? It seems like it should be easy but I'm stuck on what the order of a product would be, other than that it divides the product of the orders of each element.

Comment: Why $h=g^{-1}$ wouldn't work?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418287/possible-order-of-ab-when-order-of-a-and-b-are-known). Thank you, @PaulPlummer

Answer (score 1):

If $h = g^{-1}$, then $gh = e$, so $(gh)^m = e^m = e$, so the order of $(gh)^m$ is $1$ (and if $n\neq 1$, which it will be if $g\neq e$, then this is a contradiction to the statement). In general, the order of $(gh)^m$ need not have any relation to the orders of $g$ and $h$: If you consider the group generated by two elements $g$ and $h$ such that $g^2 = h^2 = e$, but $gh\neq hg$, then $(gh)^2$ to any nonzero power will not be the identity, so $(gh)^2$ has infinite order (and $\infty$ doesn't divide $4$). In a finite abelian group you can say more: see Eric Naslund's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67180/order-of-product-of-two-elements-in-a-group).