# Order of span of product of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $A,B\leq G$. Is there some formula of the sort
$$|\langle AB \rangle| = f(|A|,|B|,|A\cap B|,\ldots)$$
to get the order of the span of $AB$ as a function of some known quantities?

I'm using "$\ldots$" in my formula because there must be other parameters at play than the first three: consider these two options.

- $A=\{1,(12)\},B=\{1,(13)\}$
- $A=\{1,(12)\},B=\{1,(34)\}$

In both cases, $A,B\leq \Sigma_4$, $|A|=|B|=2$ and $|A\cap B|=1$. But in the first case $|\langle AB \rangle|=6$ and in the second $|\langle AB \rangle|=4$.

So I'm asking an open question in some sort here.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a formula for the order of the subgroup $\langle A,B \rangle$ generated by $A$ and $B$. There won't be such a formula, since $\langle A,B \rangle$ heavily depends on the relations between the elements of $A$ and $B$. Notice that these relations can be arbitrary long words in the free product of $A$ and $B$ (such as $a_1 b_1 a_2 b_3 a_3 = 1$). This already happening when $A$, $B$ are cyclic. See [Possible order of $ab$ when orders of $a$ and $b$ are known.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418287/)

The problem is only feasible if $AB$ is already a subgroup, in which case we have the [usual formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k#168946).

My guess is that this question actually arises in the context of a different, manageable problem. In that case, I recommend that you post that problem instead.

Comment: Got me... I hoped to be able hide the XY. I'm trying to prove the Sylow theorems. No hints, thanks!

Comment: Feel free to check this out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833493/proof-of-existence-of-p-subgroups

Comment: I kindly ask you to not ping me for questions in this way. Also, I ask you to accept this answer since apparently it has answered your original question. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misremembered the comment "I recommend that you post that problem instead" and thought you had shown interest in knowing what the main problem was. My bad.